# mysql запрос limit

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql

Стоит задача, есть 2 таблицы вопросы и ответы(questions, answers)
надо вытащить рандомно из 10 вопросов 2 вопроса со всеми ответами(ответов может быть 5 или 4 или 6)

```
select  from ( select  from answers ) a, questions q where a.id_question = q.id limit 1
```

сделал такой запрос но он выдает 1 вопрос и только 1 ответ а у этого вопроса 5 ответов. Как написать sql запрос чтоб вытащить 2 рандомных вопроса со всеми его ответами?

Comment: вам надо ограничить выборку из  таблицы вопросов, а вы ограничиваете зачем-то всю выборку

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM ( SELECT *
       FROM questions
       ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 2 ) q
JOIN answers a ON a.id_question = q.id
```

Comment: огромное спасибо за помощь)

Answer (score 1):

> Как написать sql запрос чтоб вытащить 2 рандомных вопроса со всеми его
>   ответами?

Так с SQL не работают. limit всего лишь ограничивает выдачу (количество строк в результате запроса).

Нужно либо получить из БД все вопросы и выбрать два случайно. Либо для вопросов сделать ключевое поле и забирать из таблицы вопросы по конкретным ключам, предварительно случайно выбрав ключи.

Comment: *Так с SQL не работают. limit всего лишь ограничивает выдачу (количество строк в результате запроса).* Что за [censored]? то есть в запросе ограничивать можно, а в подзапросе - не моги, что ли? несерьёзно.

Comment: @Akina это вопрос подхода а не возможностей SQL. В подзапросе - можно ограничивать. Но  нет смысла городить подзапрсы в джоинах если можно просто сделать два запроса. Один на вопросы и выбрать два случайных. Другой запрос для ответов на конкретные вопросы.

Comment: *это вопрос подхода а не возможностей SQL.* Увы, это вопрос подхода со стороны клиентского ЯП. А вот со стороны SQL два запроса всегда менее эффективны, чем один комплексный. *нет смысла городить подзапрсы в джоинах если можно просто сделать два запроса* Я просто не в курсе, насколько древняя у автора версия MySQL. В современных условиях подзапрос улетает в CTE, и мы имеем практически то, что получается в случае двух запросов, только экономятся и трафик, и ресурсы на работу планировщика, а иной раз ещё и более эффективный план строится.

Comment: @Akina Подход здесь в том что автору скорее всего не нужна таблица где все в кучу. Вопросы по пять раз дублируются (для строки с ответом будет поле вопрос поле ответ и ещё 100500 полей мы же * поставили). Потом он у нас сделает фильтр уберёт лишнее. Нужно дробить задачу на элементарные логические единицы, а не бить по площадям.